# WFFM: How to move uploaded files from Web to Master database

Tags: wffm, configuration, media-library

We are using Sitecore 8.1 update-1 with WFFM 8.1. We are using 2 CD servers and both servers we have given the msterdatabase as below in Sitecore.Forms.config

```
      <setting name="WFM.MasterDatabase" value="web" />
```

When we try to upload the files through WFFM file upload field, the uploaded files are getting added to Web database media library.

How can we move these files to Master database, any suggestions?

Comment: can you check if is same scenario here : https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/sitecore-wffm-file-upload-no-master-db

Comment: @Sitecore Climber, No its not the same scenario. For me the files are getting saved in Web database there is no error. But i want those files to be saved in master database. Is there any way to move it.?

Comment: what happen s if you change WFM.MasterDatabase to master value ?

Comment: When i use the master database not able to submit the form. Getting error"System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Source: Sitecore.Forms.Custom at Sitecore.Form.UI.Adapters.FileUploadAdapter.AdaptResult(Object value) " . so as per this link http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/web_forms_file_upload_2_exceptions_common_errors/ i have updated to web database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Problem

The problem that you are facing is that the CD servers do not have access to the `master` database. This is intentional, as your CDs should not, in concept, need access to the `master` database and so it's better for security if they do not have access to it.

#### User Generated Content

From a user-generated content (UGC) standpoint, however, this poses some issues. If you want your authors to be able to see what users uploaded in Sitecore then this isn't feasible. Since your CM is the instance that has access to the `master` database, one option is to create a service on the CM that will upload your data to the `master` database. I do not recommend this, if you're maximizing your securities, since the CM server should never be open to the public.

#### Typical Recommendation: Custom Viewer

As such, I typically inform my clients up front that when users submit uploaded content it will not go to the `master` database, if they have a split CM and CD. If the client would like the ability to view this data from the CM, I offer to write them a custom viewer that they can access from the launchpad. I try to avoid offering to teach them to switch databases to the `web` database, as - more often than not - doing so tends to cause more issues down the line (client editing in the wrong DB, etc.).

#### Alternative: Service to Copy from `web` to `master`

Another option is to have a service that runs on your CM, that is responsible for pulling the items from the `web` database and recreating them in the `master` database.

You could create a scheduled task that crawls the section of your `web` database's Media Library that contains WFFM-uploaded media, downloads the media and uploads it into Sitecore. You should, of course, include support for comparing with what has already been copied to the `master` DB, so that you don't copy the same item twice. You can do this by ensuring that the item you copy into the `master` database has the same ID as the item from the `web` database. If you do so, you should also copy all of the field contents, as well.